# Spring boot in-memory DynamoDB/DAX solution for functional tests?

Tags: java, spring, amazon-dynamodb

Is there a way to configure an in-memory DynamoDB/DAX instance to be used for functional testing in the same way as what Spring `embedded-redis` module allows? I have not found much documentation online on how to achieve or of working with DynamoDB locally with Java either, some examples would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.html

Quoting from docs,

> The downloadable version of DynamoDB lets you write and test
>   applications without accessing the DynamoDB web service. Instead, the
>   database is self-contained on your computer. When you're ready to
>   deploy your application in production, you can make a few minor
>   changes to the code so that it uses the DynamoDB web service.

Comment: Yes but a) documentation is somewhat poor and b) this is about connecting to a local instance, not running an instance embedded within the application within functional test context

Comment: I don't think DDB has anything like that as of now, but I may be wrong. I am not exactly sure what you mean by functional tests. If you are talking about Integration tests, may be this post can help https://thecarlhall.wordpress.com/2015/11/14/integration-testing-with-dynamodb-locally/.